# How to monitor when assign onclick propertise on object javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I monitor when a object was assigned a `onclick` propertise ?
I want to notified when a handler is assigned.

```
<input type="text" id="test">

<script>
var testObj = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(testObj.onclick); // return null

testObj.onclick = function () { // assign handler
    console.log("Clicked !!");
}

console.log(testObj.onclick); // return function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
var target = document.getElementById('test');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if ( mutation.type == "attributes" && mutation.attributeName == "onclick" )
    {
       console.log("onclick assigned");
    }
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
testObj.addEventListener("click",function () {
    console.log("Clicked !!");
});
```

Here is example:
https://jsbin.com/sewuyuyahu/edit?html,output

Comment: Your code use `addEventListener` function. But my problem is monitor when we assign properties to a object.

Comment: So change this
console.log( testObj.onclick );
for this:
console.log( testObj.onclick() );

Comment: I think the OP is trying to ask how to tell whether a handler has been assigned. Or how to be notified when a handler is assigned. It's a little unclear, but not asking how to assign a handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right! I want to notified when a handler is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an event which JavaScript fires upon calling `addEventListener` or `element.onlcik`.

As a dirty workaround, you could call a additional your own function to 
notify/monitor added events.

```
//Example

registerEvent(obj, eventname) {
    //save this for monitoring purpose.
}

//Notify here...
registerEvent(testObjet, 'onclick');
testObj.onclick = function () { // assign handler
    console.log("Clicked !!");
}
```